# Subviews moving out of place when parent view is rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm following this guide here: http://guti.in/articles/creating-tinder-like-animations/ in order to recreate a Tinder-like swiping card effect.

Long story short, I have a UIView with a PanGestureRecognizer set to do the following:

```
- (void)dragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGFloat xDistance = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x;
    CGFloat yDistance = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].y;

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            self.originalPoint = self.center;
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xDistance / 320, 1);
            CGFloat rotationAngel = (CGFloat) (2*M_PI * rotationStrength / 16);
            CGFloat scaleStrength = 1 - fabsf(rotationStrength) / 4;
            CGFloat scale = MAX(scaleStrength, 0.93);
            self.center = CGPointMake(self.originalPoint.x + xDistance, self.originalPoint.y + yDistance);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngel);
            CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
            self.transform = scaleTransform;

            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            [self resetViewPositionAndTransformations];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:break;
    }
}
- (void)resetViewPositionAndTransformations
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
        self.center = self.originalPoint;
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    }];
}
```

However, unlike the view in the example, mine has multiple different subviews, and I'm finding that when I apply this code, I get this erroneous result:

Before Swipe:
[image]

During Swipe:
[image]

As you can see, it seems as if the subviews are "sliding" out of place, so to speak. What's worse, when the swipe is over, the subviews are left looking slightly out of place, even though the parent view is in the right place. If you're curious, my constraints look like:
[image]

If anyone could help me get the subviews to move correctly with the superview, I would really appreciate it. One thing I've found sort-of remedies the last problem is to store the original centers of each of the subviews and restore them to that at the end, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

**EDIT: I'm still haven't come up with a fix, but I'm now 99.9% sure it's to do with the constraints of the subviews**.

Comment: Can you try to "disable" the rotation transformation and see if the problem persists? Trying to understand what causes the subviews to move out of place - if that rotation isn't causing it try to disable the position change as well (comment out self.center)

Comment: I did try disabling the rotation, and I found that stopped the subviews from moving out of place. Additionally, I also found disabling autolayout would let me do all the animations but keep everything where it's supposed to be. Of course, it has the drawback of not auto-resizing to fit different screen sizes.